# In CSS what does it mean when only the property name is crossed out but not the value?

Tags: css

So I know that when you see a CSS property crossed out, it means that it's being override by a more specific rule, but in the pic below you can see that the margin **property** is crossed out, but the **value** is not. What does that mean?

[image]

Comment: Firefox is easier to use for layout

Comment: What browser are you using? Mine (Edge/Chrome) shows the crossing out on top of the 30px and so on, not just in the gaps in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is also crossed-out/striked-through but it is not properly visible because the striking/crossing line goes underneath the number and 'px'. You can still see that line where there is space in between. Also, last semi-colon is striked, so you can verify it this way.

Hope you agree with my perspective.